# Registered office as domain name whois address

Tags: domains

if I have a company that  has a registered office (not a real one) in London, is it ok to use that address as the one for my domain name?

Comment: I would think so, especially if you have registered it with an authority?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which organisation is ultimately responsible for the top level domain, but for .com, .org and others, it's [ICANN](http://www.icann.org/en/resources/registrars/consensus-policies/wdrp/faqs). They say

> Your domain name registration agreement with your registrar requires
>   that you keep this information accurate and current.

The reason:

> ...it is available to be searched by members of the public in order to
>   allow rapid resolution of technical problems and to permit enforcement
>   of consumer protection, trademark, and other laws

So the address is OK if someone can get hold of you at that address for the reasons mentioned there.